# Deploying Spring 4.0.1 application fails

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is my context definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

 <context:annotation-config/>


 <context:component-scan base-package="com.brain" />



 <bean id="seguridadFilter" class="com.brain.core.configuracion.SeguridadFilter">
 </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
     <property name="jndiName" value="JNDI" />
     <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
     <property name="cache" value="true" />
     <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
 </bean>


 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>
     <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:com/brain/core/hibernate/dao/hibernate.cfg.xml" />   


 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="programacionTareasCore" class="com.brain.core.common.ProgramacionTareasCore" />

 <bean id="schedulerTask" 
       class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
     <property name="targetObject" ref="programacionTareasCore" />
     <property name="targetMethod" value="configuracion" />
 </bean>    

 <bean id="timerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
     <property name="timerTask" ref="schedulerTask" />
     <property name="delay" value="20000" />
     <property name="period" value="60000" />
 </bean>
```

But after deployment I'm getting the following error:

```
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 69 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 69; columnNumber: 42; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: No está permitido que el atributo 'local' aparezca en el elemento 'ref'.
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The exception log said that applicationContext.xml is invalid, are you sure the applicationContext.xml file is well-formed and correct?

Comment: I only changed the version of my spring , from 3.1.2 to 4.0.1 . That's correct ? . Sorry im noobie in spring

Comment: `Line 69 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]` , take a look what is on line 69 , you are probably missing a close or open xml tag

Comment: The error means this : Grave:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 69 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 69; columnNumber: 42; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Not that allowed this attribute 'local' appears in the element 'ref'

Comment: is this fragment of code :   <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
        <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
            <list>
                <ref local="timerTask" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `local` attribute has been removed in Spring 4.0, here's [Juergen Hoeller explanation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/0fc5a5d912a4548f9bbf6f14024dc489d94cb2c9):

> Removed the ref 'local' attribute in spring-beans-4.0.xsd since 'local' lost its differentiating role to a regular bean ref back in the 3.1 days when we started allowing for the same bean id to reappear in a different beans section of the same configuration file (with a different profile).

Replace all occurences of `local` with `bean`, i.e.:

```xml
<ref local="timerTask" />
```

becomes

```xml
<ref bean="timerTask" />
```

Comment: But running the project i got another error... is that :  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean

Comment: @JuanCarlosVerdeCortez please post it as a new question, including all the details in the question body (not title or comments), it will increase your chances of someone helping you to solve the problem. ...or simply try to search for an answer - looks like `MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean` was deprecated as of Spring 3.